# Размещение сайта в iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

У большинства сайтов установлен заголовок `X-Frame-Options`... можно ли его как-то обойти?

Или как поставить во фрейм сайт, если установлен заголовок `X-Frame-Options`?

Comment: А для чего это понадобилось?

Answer (score 1):

#### В клиенте, поддерживающем заголовок `X-Frame-Options` — никак.

Этот механизм предназначен для того, чтобы защитить пользователей от атак путём **кликджекинга**. Механизм подробно описан в [RFC 7034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034).

Гипотетически, пользователь может **на свой страх и риск** пользоваться клиентом, в котором поддержка этого заголовка отключена или вырезана: это может быть настройка, расширение или просто форк браузера, где это отключено прямо в исходном коде. И **либо клиент сам создаёт такую ситуацию** (хочется верить, осознавая возможные последствия), **либо пользуется чужим клиентом** (которому не должен доверять).